# Notepad++ won't execute the conditions in my if else statement, even though it does execute my prompt function?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, notepad++

So, I think I should mention that pretty much all of my js knowledge is the knowledge that Codecademy could give, for those who know it. JSHint said that everything looked fine once I fixed some of my other issues, but when I run it, only the prompt works, then the screen just sits there blankly.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var color = prompt("What is your favorite color");
        if(color == "yellow"){
            console.log("I see you have good taste");
        }
        else{
            console.log("That color sucks");
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Which screen sits there blankly? The page? Then everything works as expected. The console? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log()` prints out on developer console and does not appears on page unlike `prompt`, use `alert()` instead of `console.log()`.

```js
var color = prompt("What is your favorite color");
if (color == "yellow") {
  alert("I see you have good taste");
} else {
  alert("That color sucks");
}
console.log('User picked color = ',color);
```